# Images going blank after a while

Tags: images

After inserting my images as a PNG, they displayed as expected but after a while they go blank

i noticed " pagespeed.ic.N2uHZILiyd.webp " added to my images right after .png  ex : https:examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/xKayak.png.pagespeed.ic.RTxA7TYiFj.webp

i'm not using any plugin to speed the load my pages

How can i solve this please ?

Comment: We're going to need more information. Are you using a plugin to speed up your page loads? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/392983/edit) to provide more context.

Comment: Also, looking at the source of that page, I see no evidence it's running WordPress. You might be on the wrong StackExchange site.

Comment: @PatJ im not using any plugin to speed up my pages. i have inserted a new link for image example